# ArangoDB - Get edge information while using traversals

Tags: arangodb

I'm interested in using traversals to quickly find all the documents linked to an initial document. For this I'd use:

`let id = 'documents/18787898'
for d in documents 
   filter d._id == id
   for i in 1..1 any d edges 
      return i`

This generally provides me with all the documents related to the initial ones. However, say that in these edges I have more information than just the standard `_from` and `_to`. Say it also contains `order`, in which I indicate the order in which something is to be displayed. Is there a way to also grab that information at the same time as making the traversal? Or do I now have to make a completely separate query for that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, but your graph traversal is slightly incorrect.

The way I read the [documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html), it shows that you can return `vertex`, `edge`, and `path` objects in a traversal:

```
FOR vertex[, edge[, path]]
  IN [min[..max]]
  OUTBOUND|INBOUND|ANY startVertex
  edgeCollection1, ..., edgeCollectionN
```

I suggest adding the edge variable `e` to your `FOR` statement, and you do not need to find document/vertex matches first (given than `id` is a single string), so the `FOR`/`FILTER` pair can be eliminated:

```
LET id = 'documents/18787898'
FOR v, e IN 1 ANY id edges 
   RETURN e
```

Comment: Do you happen to know of any way to also get the collection information? In this case I use a single edge collection, but what if I use several and I want to know what collection the edge is from?

Comment: The only way to do that is to look at the `from` and `to` properties.  The edge collection will be identified in the `<collection>/<key` format.  Using "named graphs" may help though, as you don't have to specify the specific edge collection to use.  It may look daunting, but I've found named graphs to be indispensable.